# Problem with Automated Testing & Wrong Formula

Tags: java, automated-tests, bluej

Im in an intro to java programming course and we're doing a project in Bluej where we need to use automated testing to run our code. The test code is given and cannot be changed, and we have to write code and run the tests successfully. Mine is all running smoothly except for this last part. Here is a snippet from the test code:

```
    public void test_spray() {
        int currentRoaches = population.getRoaches();
        population.spray(20);     // reduce the population by 20%
        assertEquals((int)(currentRoaches * 0.80), population.getRoaches() );
    }
```

And here is the method I wrote for it. It compiles but when I run it through the test I get a failed error that says "expected:<160> but was:<180>" I thought I had the formula correct but I guess not.

```
 /* simulates spraying with insecticide, which reduces the population
    by the given percentage. */ 
    public void spray(double givenPercentage) {
        this.population = this.population - (int)givenPercentage;
    }
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Any insight would be awesome. Thanks in advance!

Comment: One great way to debug a program is to assign numbers to it and walk through it on paper.  Let's say you have 200 roaches.  Reducing by 20% = 0.8 * 200 = 160.  Your formula subtracts the percentage as if it was a number of roaches, so 200 - 20 = 180.  If you could write the assertEquals statement, though, I'm not sure why you think the spray method should be written differently.  Flagging as a typo

Comment: I cannot write the assertEquals statement. Its part of the test file that I cannot change. It was given to me along with the project.

Comment: Ah, that explains it.  I see you've got a solution, but I'd still recommend researching "percentages," since that is a concept that will come up again and again in programming.  It's also just a necessary life skill for calculating prices in the store and whatnot.

Answer (score 1):

You are subtracting `givenPercentage` as an absolute number. What you are looking for is to subtract percentage of population. 20% of 200 is 40. 200-40=160. Correct code:

```
public void spray(double givenPercentage) {
    this.population = this.population - (int)((givenPercentage/100) * this.population);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! I put what you provided in and the test is still unsuccessful, saying "expected:<160> but was:<200>" :(

Comment: This answer does not work.  You cast `givenPercentage` to an integer.  Then you divide by `100`.  But this is **integer division**, so as long as `givenPercentage` is less than `100`, you should end up with `0`.  So then you have `this.population - 0 * this.population`, which is the same as just `this.population`.  What you want to do is find the coefficient using floating-point math, do the multiplication in floating-point, and only **then** cast the final result to an integer.

Comment: My suggestion: `this.population = (int) ((1 - givenPercentage / 100) * this.population)`

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong, I think your suggestion is wrong. Input to spray is 20, not 0.2 regardless of type being double.

Comment: Oops, sorry for types confusion :)  @kibben, give it a try now.

Comment: @Marcin My suggestion is equivalent to what you have now.  You just have it in expanded form.  Since `this.population` is a factor of both of your terms, you can factor it out, resulting in my expression above.  As for the 20 vs 0.2, note that I do divide it by 100.  Order of operations says that division comes before subtraction, so it gets divided by 100 before being subtracted from 1.  Either way is valid, I was just saving a few characters :)

Comment: thank you thank you thank you guys!! it worked :)